Question about computer screen
Where would a question about a computer screen (I had a computer screen in mind when I asked the question but maybe the question is more generally about the display technology itself and less about how it interfaces with the computer) better fit?
If it better fits here I would welcome a migration. I'd think about the tags led, display, diode, optoelectronics, optics.
I asked What is the difference between NanoLED and MicroLED computer screens is it just a marketing gimmick? in SuperUser.SE.
Both are allegedly self-emmissive both turn electricity into light so I don't see a difference other than the different emmiter name (with a trademark sign).


This is a site about electrical design questions, this fits more of an electrical use question (a question about how something works is more often than not off topic here). We can't migrate questions from other sites, that action comes from the source site. I would not recommend migration.
EDIT:
This site is for electronics and electrical engineering professionals, students, and enthusiasts. We ask and answer questions about electrical and electronics engineering topics, which include electronics, physical computing, and those working with microcontrollers, Arduinos and embedded systems. We feel the best Electronics Design questions have a schematic, links to pertinent datasheets or some source code in them, but if your question generally covers …
a specific electronics design problem
the theory and simulation of electromagnetic forces
a communication scheme
the writing of firmware for bare-metal or RTOS applications


Even if the how something works (how 2 tecnologies are different actually) is answered with electrical engineering principles (or material science)? What exactly are the Led, Diode and Display (maybe Optoelectronics, Appliances etc) tags? I don't see much difference between my question and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/723500/what-is-led-starter https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/134561/do-blown-fluorescent-lights-still-use-electricity?rq=1 I am asking similar things about a different technology.

Yes, How is your question a design question?

It was a mistake of mine (I am not interested in making a panel but understanding how it illuminates how it shows pictures) fudge both desing and circuit design that still leaves Led, Diode, Display, Optoelectronics, Optics. I am certainly not asking about how to use it. I am asking about the science behind how it shows pictures.

But in the end the question may be a question of design and circuit design (isn't a led panel a circuit)? Especially if what Mokubai said is correct (I don't understand what he is saying exactly) "That said, just look closely at the image. You can clearly see the difference just by looking at the LED stages. One has single colour elements, the other shows a lot of little dots." Are the single colour elements implying a single pixel in the red band? People unproblematically ask about the working principle https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/467180/magnetron-working-principle.

The meta site is for asking about topics related to EE.SE, you didn't answer how this is a design question (it isn't) and you can't ask unrelated questions on the meta. Please drop the subject, it's not on topic.

Isn't it a design question? If the difference in displays is the elements of the led that I think is a design. But even if it isn't a design question why not simply scrap the 2 design tags? There are many questions without the design tag.

I am not trying to argue (convince them of my position) I am trying to understand what they are saying. Why is a problem even if my question isn't a design question (besided the mistaging)? There are so many questions that have little to do with design.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

I haven't looked into this subject for a long time, so I might be wrong. But from a first glance the terms MicroLED and NanoLED seem to be marketing names for consumer electronics, not fundamental technologies. If that's the case, it would fall into the off-topic category "Don't ask about... Consumer electronics such as media players, cell phones or smart phones, except when designing these products or modifying their electronics for other uses" (from the Tour).

@Velvet But I am asking what the difference is. If it is true an answer could well be the difference is marketing names no different technology.

@VoltageSpike The help says "We feel the best Electronics Design questions...." It doesn't say that you can only ask about Electronics Design. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/723500/what-is-led-starter What is LED starter? is a perfectly fine (4 upvotes) non design question. I can't understand how that question is a design question while mine isn't.

@VoltageSpike Is How are NanoLED and MicroLED computer screens designed differently? Better?

I think this is definitely an Electrical Engineering question, because Photonics is mostly found in the EE dept of universities. As a photonics researcher in an EE dept, this is exactly the kind of question I'd expect to see on an EE site.  There is No real photonics, microelectronics or microfabrication section of SE yet.

@Demis https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62257/how-are-nanoled-and-microled-computer-screens-designed-differently
